# FastAPI create model whose values are conditionally dependent on another model

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I've been working on an API for a while and something I'm not sure can be done is making possible values of a model dependent on another model's value. So I have something like this:

```
class Names(str, Enum):
    nombre1 = 'John'
    nombre2 = 'Paul'


class Pets(str, Enum):
    pet1 = 'cat'
    pet2 = 'dog'
    pet3 = 'parrot'
    pet4 = 'rat'


@app.get('/test')
def test_this(name: Names, pet: Pets) -> Response:
    print(name, pet)
    return {'response': f'{name.value} {pet.value}'}
```

This works as showing me all 4 pets as possible values with no connection to the selected name. What I do want, is to have my pet options reduced based on what's the inputted name. So, if the name is John I only want as options `cat` and `dog` and if it's Paul I want as options `parrot` and `rat`.

The idea is that this reflects on the swagger so if I do something like this:

[image]

It should show me only cat and dog in this case. Is this even possible? Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't think so. In this GET request you ask a client to give a `name` and a `pet`. You cannot know upfront what the client will send as a `name`. So you will always end up in your function body.